# Knockout Validation on Nested View Model

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I am looking to use a combination of the KnockoutJS libarary, the Knockout.Mapping plugin, and the Knockout-Validation plugin to display some data that the user can manipulate.

My data is coming over as a nested object from an AJAX call, and I run that data through the mapping plugin to create a Knockout view model, customizing the validation rules with the mapping options object in ko.mapping.fromJS.

I have been successful in getting objects at the first layer (name in the Fiddle below) to show a message if the field is empty, however objects that are nested (IntroData.PlanName) do not show the validation message. Do I need to setup the mapping object differently for these nested objects?

ViewModel (sample of what is coming in my AJAX call):

```
var stuff = {
    IntroData: {
        PlanName: 'Test'
    },
    name: 'tes2s3t'
};
```

Mapping:

```
var validationMapping = {
    IntroData: {
        PlanName: {
            create: function (options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data).extend({
                    required: true
                });
            }
        }
    },
    name: {
        create: function (options) {
            return ko.observable(options.data).extend({
                required: true
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Hookup:

```
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    grouping: {
        deep: true
    }
}, true);

window.viewModel = ko.validatedObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff, validationMapping));

ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odxv53g9/5/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not clear on this, but apparently `ko.mapping.fromJS()` ignores nested mappings, so the "create" method for PlanName never gets called.

You could add an explicit mapping for IntroData instead:

```
IntroData: {
    create: function (options) {
        var nestedMapping = {
            PlanName: {
                create: function (options) {
                    return ko.observable(options.data).extend({
                        required: true
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, nestedMapping);
    }        
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odxv53g9/6/